# How to connect a Windows Container to a service running on localhost?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2022

I need to be able to connect to an existing postgresql database running on port 5432 of my laptop. The database is not going to be containerized. This is for a **Windows host running Windows containers**.

As a basic test:

- Docker Desktop is installed, configured for Windows Containers
- Docker Engine is set to use WSL 2
- User had been added to 'docker-users' group
- From VS 2022 create a Asp.net web app from the template with Docker Support enabled
- Run in 'Debug', all works fine and the App comes up.

Default Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerTest001.csproj", "."]

RUN dotnet restore "./DockerTest001.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "DockerTest001.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerTest001.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest001.dll"]
```

**First Problem**

If I try to build the image with a right-click on the Dockfile **Build Docker Image** it will run as far as `dot restore` then falls over. This appears to be due to the `dotnet` commands running from within the container which cannot access any external resources, i.e. it can't see the internet.

This can be worked around by basically tricking the DockerEngine to use a specific DNS; in this case `1.1.1.1`. This is **REALLY BAD!!!** we should not need to trick DockerEngine.

In DockerDesktop -> Settings -> DockerEngine add `"dns": [ "1.1.1.1" ]`, so that the full Json reads as:

```
{
  "dns": [
    "1.1.1.1"
  ],
  "experimental": false
}
```

This gets round the first hurdle of being able to build the Docker Image, but doesn't resolve any of the connectivity issues.

**This doesn't fail in debug as VS is passing your local nuget repos to the container, hence it doesn't have to reach out to nuget**

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest001.dll"]
```

To explore the connectivity problems you can keep the default Dockerfile and comment out the `ENTRYPOINT` line to allow to start the container in an interactive mode and poke around the network settings.

Right-click `Build Docker Image` and this should build and deploy to Docker.

From VS Containers window you can run this Interactive or from Docker Desktop.

Run `ping 8.8.8.8` and it should give a response.

If I try `ipconfig /all` I get back something like:

Windows IP Configuration

```
  Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 121452dfd949
  Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
  Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
  IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
  WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
```

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

```
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
  Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-16-BD-7D
  DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c3:d832:930e:c04d%4(Preferred)
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.33.89(Preferred)
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.32.1
  DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 67114333
  DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2C-71-03-4F-00-15-5D-16-BD-7D
  DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.22.32.1
                                      1.1.1.1
  NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

IPv4 Address should be the one the container is running on.
DNS Servers lists 2, the `1.1.1.1` address we set earlier and it's Default Gateway.

I can ping the `1.1.1.1` address and it gives a response, but the Default Gateway returns `Request timed out`.

I can also try `ping host.docker.internal` which gives a similar `Request timed out` response but lets me know that `host.docker.internal` maps to `192.168.1.171`.

At this point I'm running out of options :-(

By default the windows containers should be on the `nat` network. So in a Terminal on the host run `docker network ls` and it gives

```
NETWORK ID     NAME             DRIVER    SCOPE
358ec7a27af1   Default Switch   ics       local
47dfaa722afb   WSL              ics       local
fdd3f70b0911   nat              nat       local
12b69a800f54   none             null      local
```

Inspecting the nat network with `docker network inspect nat`:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "nat",
        "Id": "fdd3f70b0911be48f72f4c45f89d114141d1a2764e3aedc8542ebf52a7c8270f",
        "Created": "2023-08-18T10:34:22.4768098+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "nat",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "windows",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.22.32.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "172.22.32.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "121452dfd949cea62abe99b525dec934446f1ace4fa4921cec68fef2cb3a02e7": {
                "Name": "thirsty_antonelli",
                "EndpointID": "04f1e7c223aae2b186da5d26fc6d93e621f9569e9ddd5bcd671100292c6d1b08",
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:16:bd:7d",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.33.89/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid": "E9DD9AB5-D040-40C1-AE38-D6ACF309F423",
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.networkname": "nat"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

From here the Default Gateway and IpAddress of the container tally correctly.

At this point I've run out of options.

For interest I repeated the same process with a Linux container and spun a dev website on `https:\\localhost:5001` and was able to curl and receive a response for the website running on the host.

Comment: Is the database binding on the local IP that host.docker.internal maps to, or is it listening on localhost? Unless I'm overlooking it in the wall of text, you only mention the port it is listening on. EDIT: Oh wait - I may be getting container internal VS external IP address mixed up. Containers make my head hurt.

Comment: Ha ha, It's been making my head hurt all week :-)

Comment: Frustratingly this works with Linux Containers, and the fact that the dotnet restore on a basic Dockerfile doesn't work makes me think it's an issue with the default setup. This is something that should just work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Corporate policy in this instance locked down our local laptop firewall. Hence without permissions being pushed to the laptop there was no way the containers could access the local network.

Trying this all again on a clean VM with the firewall permissions in place and the hypervisor correctly configured did allow this to work.